# How can you run a python script from raspberry pi when a respective button is pressed in android studio?

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, opencv, raspberry-pi

Basically when the button is pressed in android studio I want my python function to open the raspberry pi camera module 2.

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this a tensorflow question ?